# Is it a requirement to start a gif frame datastream with a clear code?

Tags: gif, animated-gif

The specification doesn't make it clear:

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

> The Clear code can appear at
>   any point in the image data stream and therefore requires the LZW algorithm to
>   process succeeding codes as if a new data stream was starting. **Encoders should
>   output a Clear code as the first code of each image data stream.**

"Should" doesn't sound like a requirement. If the code table for my previous frame is optimal and I wish to reuse it, why should I bother recreating the same exact thing and wasting final filesize on that? As it turns out, this frame is identical to the previous (just a different xy), and will be nearly 25% smaller on just the second iteration. As I roll through reusing the codetable, I still won't bust the 12bit max, and I'll be able to paste copies of this frame for just a few bytes each.

So far though, most viewers don't agree. Chrome loads it without complaining, but shows a blank white tab. OSX Preview complains that it's not the right format. And Gimp shows the second frame as a layer, but with garbled pixel data... I'm only using 8 colors, but the color picker tool is showing pixels to have index values of 143, 18, 44, and so on (which don't seem to be available in the code table at that point... I'm only up to about 98 codes when the index 143 shows up).

If this is a case of these implementations not following the spec correctly, which others might I test against? What's the most likely to follow it to the letter?

Answer (score 0):

> "Should" doesn't sound like a requirement

Yes, the specification used "should" instead of "must". But whether or not the first code is "clear" code, there should a a contract between the encoder and the decoder. Since GIF image doesn't save string table along with the compressed stream, the "LZW' decoding process must reconstruct the original table as it goes starting with an initialized string table. This initial table comes from what knowledge we have about the number of possible pixel values for the current frame and it is translated into "minimum code length" which is put right before the "LZW" stream and that it the only information a "LZW" decoder will need to crunch out it's string table.

The truth is even if there is no "clear code" issued by a GIF encoder at the start of LZW decoding, any GIF (LZW) decoder "must" initialize it's string table before it actually starts decoding LZW stream using the minimum code length value read from the input. This forms the contract between the encoder and the decoder and that keeps the encoder and decoder in sync.

If as you said, you want to keep the previous string table and even the next frame is exactly the same as the previous frame, then the encoder and the decoder will not have the same string table to use. That's why all the strange behaviors you saw when you tested your approach.

So unless the GIF specification is changed to save string table, your approach won't work.